# How to use bind(this) in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am using react with app with `class App extends React.Component<{}, MyState>`

The below code works well when I used javascript. But below code has error in typescript

```
socket.onopen = (function() {
    console.log("ws opened!!.");  
    this.setState({
      a: true,
      b: false,
    })  
}).bind(this);
```

However, the error occurred

> 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation

How can I fix this error?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: See [`this` at Runtime in Classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-at-runtime-in-classes) in the handbook

Comment: You should use an arrow function.